# Can I Layer A Grid On Top of Another Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid, overlay

You can't define the content of a window twice, but is there a way to overlay a grid on top of another grid?

In my specific case, I am creating a chess game and I want one grid to manage the pieces and their UI, and another grid to manage the black and white squares.  I want to do it this way (as opposed to using one grid with different Z indexes) because during the game I want to add Opaque Rectangles on the squares that are valid moves.  If I use a separate grid, I can clear the rectangles by doing `myGrid.Children.Clear()` in order to clean the square-UI, but keep the pieces in place.

Another solution would be to clear all children of a specific Z Index.  Is that possible?

Thanks for the help, I can post code if needed!

Comment: Currently I am using a grid and setting the Z indexes of the pieces that I want to clear to 10.  Then I iterate through the children and set the opacity of the ones with Z index == 10 to 0.  It is _very_ slow

Comment: I got something to work better... I am keeping track of what needs to be displayed in an Array of rectangles.  Every time I need to, I update the UI based on the state of the Array.  It is much much faster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Overlaying one grid on top of another:

```
<Grid>
<Grid x:Name="grid1" />
<Grid x:Name="grid2" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be exactly what I wanted.  I failed to encase both grids in another grid tag, so I was getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Adorners! An adorner is rendered in a layer seperate from that of the main window so you can have your chess board in one grid and the pieces in a grid contained within an adorner layer.
http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/21/wpf-adorners-part-1-ndash-what-are-adorners.aspx